# Sitecore jss with ionic app

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk, mobile

Has anyone tried sitecore jss app with ionic angular app or any other hybrid app which allows mobile and web deploys from same code.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, its really the start of a discussion and not the right format for SSE - you would be better off trying the community forums (https://community.sitecore.com) or [Sitecore Slack](https://sitecore.chat) for this.